# Slow response from MongoDB causing app to crash

Tags: python, mongodb

I've been storing records in Mongo and have a site where you can search through those records. Most of the time, it works lightning fast. But, there are other times where a slow connection to Mongo causes the site to crash. In my app, I create a connection with the following:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://cireyennek:mydatabaseobscured@cluster-hotkd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client["mydbname"]
col = db['mycollectionname']
openings = list(col.find())
```

It's not working now, so I ran the above in python. Creating the first three variables is super quick, but creating the openings variable can take several minutes, so I'm assuming that's what's causing the site error. Is that a correct assumption? Is there a better way to build this so I don't run into these errors?

Edit: Not sure if this is related, but looking at the opcounters, and seeing huge spikes all of a sudden. This is the graph

[image]

Comment: What's the error/exception?

Comment: The site is giving 502 and 504 errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
openings = list(col.find())
```

This does three things:

1. The server must read the entire collection from memory, or from disk if it's not already cached in memory, and send it to the client.
2. The client must receive the entire collection over the network.
3. The driver must instantiate Python objects for every document in the collection.

Each of these operations can be expensive in different ways (large collection, slow network, complex data structures like date/times needing to be parsed and instantiated).

If the collection contains, say, over 10 million documents and you are retrieving it over internet and your client is running on a laptop, it is very possible for the process to take multiple minutes.

> Is there a better way to build this so I don't run into these errors?

- Query only for the data you need, not for the whole collection.
- Index the collection based on how you query it.
- Run the database on your computer or host your application at a provider with good internet connectivity.